# D3.js Rendering topoJSON in multiple charts

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I 've been trying to plot a topoJson file in more than one chart in the DOM. The example that I am providing only includes two charts but I want to scale up eventually. My problem is that although the Javascript code is exactly the same in each of the two  containers, the topoJSON file only shows in the second container. I believe it has something to do with the rendering mode of D3, but I can not figure it out. Here's the code and the resulting page.

P.S. Sorry for the redundancy in the JS code. I only did it for the sake of the example

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="./js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="./js/topojson.js"></script>


<body>
  First Map (Empty!!!)
  <div id='container1'>

    <script charset="utf-8">

    var width=2712/9;
    var height=1955/9;
    var rasterBounds=[[-1.3312652841195303 , 41.964452901889715] , [1.748235284119533 , 43.59348149262565]];

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      .scale(1)
      .translate([0, 0])

    var b = [projection(rasterBounds[0]), projection(rasterBounds[1])],
      s = 1 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
      t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2]
    //update projection
    projection
      .scale(s)
      .translate(t)

    // geo path generator
    var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection)


    var map = d3.select('#container1').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)

    map.append("rect")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("fill", "#E6E6E6");

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["1", "2", "3"])
        .range(["#ffd633", "#aaff00" , "#267300"]);


    d3.json('MapTopoFinal.json', function(error, topology) {
            map.selectAll("path")
              .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.Fin_Map).features)
            .enter()
              .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return color(d.properties.DN);
                })
            .style("opacity", .6);
  })


     </script>
  </div>


  Second Map (OK)
  <div id='container2'>
    <script charset="utf-8">

    var width=2712/9;
    var height=1955/9;
    var rasterBounds=[[-1.3312652841195303 , 41.964452901889715] , [1.748235284119533 , 43.59348149262565]];

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      .scale(1)
      .translate([0, 0])

    var b = [projection(rasterBounds[0]), projection(rasterBounds[1])],
      s = 1 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
      t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2]
    //update projection
    projection
      .scale(s)
      .translate(t)

    // geo path generator
    var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection)


    var map = d3.select('#container2').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)

    map.append("rect")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("fill", "#E6E6E6");

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["1", "2", "3"])
        .range(["#ffd633", "#aaff00" , "#267300"]);


    d3.json('MapTopoFinal1.json', function(error, topology) {
            map.selectAll("path")
              .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.Fin_Map).features)
            .enter()
              .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return color(d.properties.DN);
                })
            .style("opacity", .6);
  })

    </script>
  </div>

</body>
```

[The resulting page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIt6Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: separating your code in multiple script tags don't creates different scopes.

Right now you are using several variables twice your script. The most important is `map`. Change the second map from this:

```
var map = d3.select('#container2').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
```

to this:

```
var map2 = d3.select('#container2').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
```

And change all subsequent `map` to `map2` or anything else. Also, change all other duplicate variables, like `color`, `projection` etc.

Don't separate your scripts like that. The way they are now, spread across the HTML, is not the best practice, because the browser has to parse each script before continuing to parse the rest of the HTML (and this can cause additional problems too). Put all your script together, inside a single `<script></script>`, at the end of the `body`.

Keep in mind that using several `<script>` tags don't define different scopes in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful comments! I followed a slightly different approach and wrapped the JS code in a function with one argument, i.e. the container div. Then I called the plotting function for each div separately

Comment: Now, using functions, you have different scopes!